# How can I setup an SSH tunnel from local Windows 10 to remote Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ssh-tunnel

I have installed [*Visual C++ 2015 for Linux*.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCppDevLabs.VisualCforLinuxDevelopment) What this does is, it takes a server name, a port number, a username, and a password, then connects to the remote machine, compiles a C++ program inside that machine, and then returns the result to my local PC.

[image]

Now, the problem I am facing is, I have to connect to the remote PC through a bastion-host machine.

Suppose, the IP address and port number of the bastion server are `yyy.yy.y.20` and `8081` respectively; the IP address of the remote machine is `xxx.xxx.x.180` but I don't know the port number.

What should be the command to create a tunnel from my local Windows 10 to the remote Linux machine?

```
ssh -L 22:xxx.xxx.x.180:22 yyy.yy.y.20:8081
```

The above command is giving me an error message:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2846]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\pc>ssh -L 22:xxx.xxx.x.180:22 yyy.yy.y.20

C:\Users\pc>ssh -L 22:xxx.xxx.x.180:22 yyy.yy.y.20:8081
ssh: Could not resolve hostname yyy.yy.y.20:8081: No such host is known.

C:\Users\pc>
```

How can I setup an SSH tunnel from local Windows 10 to remote Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

the openssh client does not support the `hostname:port` scheme. Use `-p` instead.

```
ssh -L 22:xxx.xxx.x.180:22 -p 8081 yyy.yy.y.20
```

Comment: Then what should I write on the VC++ Linux connection interface?

Comment: to connect to the tunnel? `localhost`?

Comment: what would be the port, username, and password?

Comment: You defined the port `22` in the `-L` paramater. So it seems logical to use the port 22.

Comment: username, password?

Comment: How should I know? ask whomever is responsible for the server you want to log in to.

Comment: I mean: is it Windows username password, or the Bastion server username password, or remote host username and password?

Comment: The remote host of course.

Comment: One more issue. The bastion-server actually doesn't ask for any password. I have to use a public key to connect to it. In that case, how should I modify the command?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh --help`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But, I didn't understand anything. Coz, my understanding of this matter is close to none.

Answer (score 1):

To create an SSH tunnel from your local Windows 10 machine to the remote Ubuntu machine through the bastion-host machine, you can use the following command:

```
ssh -L <local_port>:<remote_ip>:<remote_port> <bastion_username>@<bastion_ip> -p <bastion_port> -i <path_to_bastion_private_key>
```

In your case, the command would look something like this:

```
ssh -L 2222:xxx.xxx.x.180:22 bastion_username@yyy.yy.y.20 -p 8081 -i path/to/bastion/private/key
```

Here's what each parameter in the command means:

- `-L`: Specifies the local port forwarding. In this case, we're forwarding the local port `2222` to the remote Ubuntu machine's SSH port `(22)`.
- `<local_port>`: The port number on your local machine that you want to forward traffic to. In this case, we're using `2222`.
- `<remote_ip>`: The IP address of the remote Ubuntu machine you want to connect to.
- `<remote_port>`: The port number of the remote Ubuntu machine's SSH service.
- `<bastion_username>`: The username you use to connect to the bastion-host machine.
- `<bastion_ip>`: The IP address of the bastion-host machine.
- `-p`: Specifies the port number to connect to on the bastion-host machine. In this case, we're using `8081`.
- `-i`: Specifies the path to the private key file for the bastion-host machine.

Once you run the command, you'll be prompted for the password for the bastion-host machine's username. Once you enter the correct password, the tunnel will be established and you can use your Visual C++ 2015 for Linux to connect to the remote Ubuntu machine through the tunnel using the address `localhost:2222`.